# Error in Confluent Kafka Source Connector Tasks (DatagenConnector) Data Serialization into Avro Format

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to produce data from Data Source Connector with Confluent kafka DatagenConnector I am converting the value into Avro format using confluent schema registry. The configuration I am using for creating the Source connector is:

> {
> "connector.class": "io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector",
> "kafka.topic": "inventories_un3",
> "quickstart": "inventory",
> "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
> "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
> "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
> "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8083",
> "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
> "max.interval": 1000,
> "iterations": 10000000,
> "tasks.max": "1",
> "compatibility": "NONE",
> "auto.register.schemas":false,
> "use.latest.version": true
> }

The Schema registered is:

> {"schema": "{"type":"record","name":"Payment","namespace":"my.examples","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"long"},{"name":"quantity","type":"long"}, {"name":"productid","type":"long"}]}"}

Getting the following errors:

> "id": 0,
> **"state": "FAILED",
> "worker_id": "kafka-connect:8083",
> "trace": "org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler**\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:206)\n\tat org
>
> g.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)\n**Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: **Failed to serialize Avro data from topic inventories_un3 :**\n\tat** io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.fromConnectData(Converter.java:63)
> org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.lambda$convertTransformedRecord$3(WorkerSourceTask.java:329)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:156)\n\tat org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:190)\n\t... 11 more\nCaused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: **Error serializing Avro message\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:154)\n\tat** io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter$Serializer.serialize(AvroConverter.java:153)\n\tat io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.fromConnectData(AvroConverter.java:86)\n\t... 15 more\n**Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)\n\tat java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)\n\tat java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)\n\tat** java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)\n\tat java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:615)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.(HttpClient.java:242)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1258)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1192)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1086)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1020)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1372)\n\tat java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1347)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.sendHttpRequest(RestService.java:268)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.httpRequest(RestService.java:367)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:544)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:532)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.RestService.registerSchema(RestService.java:490)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.registerAndGetId(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:257)\n\tat io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.CachedSchemaRegistryClient.register(CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java:366)

Comment: What address is the schema registry available at? Are you sure it's running?

Comment: You can trouble shoot the issue further by enabling some sort of logging to capture the  source record and try to publish it via POSTMAN (if you have a KAFKA REST API) or any other client, to make sure you are able to publish the event into the topic.

Comment: As @OneCricketeer said,  generally if you are testing the confluent and did not configure the schema-registry manually then the default URL for schema-registry is localhost:8083 OR your_ip_address:8083